# Cancel Downloading in PuppeteerSharp

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I need to check if the file size is more than a given size, cancels the download.

Here is my `LaunchOptions`:

```
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = true,
    ExecutablePath = ChromePath,
    IgnoreHTTPSErrors = true,
    Args = new[] { "--disable-extensions" }
});
```

and here which I have done more:

```
await page.Client.SendAsync("Page.setDownloadBehavior", new
{
    behavior = "allow",
    downloadPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
});

await page.SetRequestInterceptionAsync(true);

page.Request += (s, er) =>
{
    if (er.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Content-Length") && Convert.ToInt64(er.Request.Headers["Content-Length"]) > GIVENSIZE)
    {
        er.Request.AbortAsync();
        return;
    }
}
```

There are two problems, the `--disable-extensions` won't work, the internet download manager will pop up to download the file, and the Request does not contain a `Content-Length` header to let me check for file size.

Any Idea?

Comment: Maybe you can somehow get the checksum by doing some low-level things involving TCP packages then find the size likewise.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the URL/Domain to [Internet Download Manager's exception list](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/register/new_faq/functions6.html). It will ignore the download request.

Comment: Internet download manager just was an example, if I disable it then the chrome itself will download the file. I need to cancel downloading by checking the file size.